# Embedding Internet explorer running in kiosk mode with customized UI

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

We want to develop an application in .net such that on the click of a button Internet Explorer should be launched.  This IE has been customized according to kiosk requirements.  The requirement is that IE should be seen and, along with it at the bottom, buttons should be seen.

Is it possible to embedd such design in a single unit such that on the button click IE becomes visible and also the buttons?

If yes what approach should be taken?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, depending on other requirements you may or may not have.  Kiosk mode is usually full screen and locked-down so users cannot exit it or switch to other apps.  If being full screen and locked-down is not a requirement:

- You could write a Shell [AppBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177%28VS.85%29.aspx) that runs in conjunction with your app that contains the buttons and logic for positioning the IE window as well.
- You could build a [Desktop Gadget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834142.aspx), if you're running on Vista or higher.
- You can just have two windows—an IE window and a custom button-containing window—and position them side-by-side.

If being full screen and locked-down is a requirement:

- You can build a horizontal [Explorer Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144099%28VS.85%29.aspx) and put your buttons inside of it.